# TFS Nuget Restore step cannot access proxy

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, nuget

We recently moved up to TFS 2017 and I'm trying to get our existing builds transitioned from XAML based ones to the new build system.  This is all behind the corporate firewall.

My test project (dotNet Core) was failing with the error...

```
Assets file '<snip>project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.
```

...so I added a Nuget Restore step to the build.  This resulted in the following error appearing in the build log...

```
<snip>
Starting: NuGet restore   
**************************************************************************
==========================================================================
Task         : NuGet Restore
Description  : Restores NuGet packages in preparation for a Visual Studio 
Build step.
Version      : 1.0.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?
LinkID=613747)
==========================================================================
C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
Active code page: 65001
```

...waits here for 30 seconds...

```
connect ETIMEDOUT 117.18.232.200:443
**************************************************************************
Finishing: NuGet restore
<snip>
```

However, checking with both Fiddler and the network people, there is no (relevant) network activity from the box at the point that it waits about 30 seconds, at the point shown.

Clearly the Nuget Restore step is attempting to access the internet but is unable to due to it being unable to access the proxy (we had a similar issue initially setting up the build server) rather than it being blocked which would show in the network logs.

If I remote to the build server and login using the same credentials as the build service I can successfully use VS to build the test project on the box, but it is obviously using the IDE config file(s) to get to the proxy.  I have configured the proxy in both the devenv.exe.config and the %appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.Config .

Can anyone suggest where else I can set it so that the Nuget Restore step can find it and use it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the steps below on your build agent machine:

- download the command line version of nuget
- add it to the path env var
- nuget.exe config -set http_proxy=http://proxy:port
- nuget.exe config -set http_proxy.user=Domain\Username
- nuget.exe config -set http_proxy.password=myPassword

---

**Update:**

The `project.assets.json` file maintains a project's dependency graph when using the PackageReference management format, which is used to make sure that all necessary packages are installed on the computer. Because this file is generated dynamically through package restore, it's typically not added to source control. As a result, this error occurs when building a project with a tool such as `msbuild` that does not automatically restore packages.

In this case, run `msbuild /t:restore` followed by `msbuild`, or use `dotnet build` (which restores packages automatically).

More details, please refer to the link below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore-troubleshooting

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work, it just updated the same file I already updated at %appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.Config

Comment: I'm actually unsure what package it wants but I would expect I can if I'm logged in, this is only a problem with remote triggered builds. If I run the build without a nuget restore I get the " ...project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file." error. That's what I'm trying to actually fix but to no avail.  I'm going to raise a Premier Support call, might as well use the service as we have access to it. ;-)

Comment: Try to add [NuGet Tool Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/tool/nuget?view=vsts) task to use NuGet 4.3.0 before nuget restore task.

Comment: Thanks for continuing to try to help.Unfortunately, I have tried that too and it suffers from the same problem, with a very similar error - neither task appears able to find the proxy settings and so cannot access the net.

Comment: Oh you flamin' hero!!!  That did it.  By adding the /t:restore switch to the msbuild arguments in the Build Solution step of the build definition, it worked!!!  Thank you sooooo much.  Obviously I have a whole heap of other tests to run now to make sure it is all good but... YAY!  My only regret is that I didn't see your updated reply before spending two plus hours getting all the stuff together to send to Premier Support for the call I logged.  Ah well, small cost.  Thanks again.